# Use different colors/shapes for scatterplot with two groups in R

Tags: r, matrix, scatter-plot, lattice

I am currently using the lattice package in R to create a scatterplot matrix, using the splom function. My dataset has two groups in it, labeled in two different columns, as such:

```
PC1 PC2 PC3 Group1 Group2
1   2   3   A      X
1   2   3   B      X
1   2   3   C      X
1   2   3   D      X
1   2   3   A      Y
1   2   3   B      Y
1   2   3   C      Y
1   2   3   D      Y
1   2   3   A      Z
1   2   3   B      Z
1   2   3   C      Z
1   2   3   D      Z
```

I can get the splom function to use different colors and shapes for one of the groups, but not for both, using the following code:

```
splom(~pcVT[,1:3], data = pcVT, xlab = NULL, groups = Group1, pch = c(1,2,3),
col = super.sym$col[1:3], panel = panel.superpose, 
key = list(points = list(pch = c(1,2,3),col = super.sym$col[1:3]),text = list(mylabels)))
```

How could I get it to use the two groups for the coloring and shapes - i.e., I want Group1 to be graphed based on color, and Group2 to be graphed based on shape. Alternatively, if splom can't do this, is there a nice way to do it using gpplot2?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your example is not reproducible and your dataset not very usable. 
I made another one...

Here is a solution with base plot :

```
d <- as.data.frame(princomp(iris[,1:4])$scores)
d$Group1 <- iris$Species
d$Group2 <- factor(sample(c("A","B","C"), 150, replace = TRUE))

mycols <- c("forestgreen", "gold", "dodgerblue")

x11(width = 16/2.54, height = 12/2.54)
pairs(d[,1:4], oma=c(3,3,6,3), 
      col = mycols[as.numeric(d$Group1)], pch = c(1:3)[as.numeric(d$Group2)], gap = 0)
legend("top", col = mycols, legend = levels(d$Group1), pch = 20, 
       xpd = NA, ncol = 3, bty = "n", inset = 0.01, pt.cex = 1.5)
legend("top", pch = 1:3, legend = levels(d$Group2), col = "black",
       xpd = NA, ncol = 3, bty = "n", inset = -0.03)
```

[image]

If you want a ggplot solution, explore the `GGally:ggpairs` possibilities (computation much slower) :

```
library(GGally)
ggpairs(data=d, mapping = aes(color = Group1, shape = Group2), 
        columns = 1:4, legend = c(2,1))
```

[image]